# Почему родительский блок меняет свой размер с :hover?

Tags: html, css

у меня присутствует ховер, который добавляет линию подчеркивания под объектом.
[image: ML[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BDiw.png)

Как видите, родительский блок меняет свою высоту, при наведении.
CSS

```
.topnav li:hover:after{
content: "";
display: block;

width: 102%;
position: relative;
top:30px;

border-bottom: 4px solid #ba0000;}
```

Я пытался создать подобный эффект и без :after, но не помогло, блок всё так же растягивается, как этого избежать?

Answer (score 3):

Очевидно, что родительский блок увеличивает свою высоту на 4px, которые добавляются при появлении нижней границы у :after.

Есть несколько способов решить проблему. Самый простой: изначально сделать у :after прозрачную границу в 4px, а по ховеру только добавлять цвет.

Также можно для li задать position: relative, а для :after - absolute. Тогда псевдоэлемент выпадет из потока, и появление границы не повлияет на высоту родительского блока.